# Force reload on client's webpage Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, database

I am new to Django development and would like to know is it possible to trigger a webpage refresh on client side.

My scenario:
Webpage 1 is being surfed by clients.

I updated some data to the database and wish to refresh the view.py to get new data from database and refresh clients webpage to display new informations.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Best Regards.

Comment: That's not very easy to do. But you could create a javascript that polls your server every few seconds in the background to check if the page needs refreshing. Your Django view would check a version number or token or something similar with the data in the db to determine if the page should be refreshed. If your js receives the answer *yes, refresh!* then it performs a `location.reload()`. Although not very user-friendly if the page is interactive and suddenly refreshes.

Comment: But django view doesn't check "version number" whenever i update it. Because I am from editing from view on webpage2. Django view of webapge 1 doesn't do any changes. Please clarify me if I am wrong.

Comment: What I mean is that page 1 needs some kind of a version number (stored in the dB). When the data is changed by page 2, the version is incremented. So when the script calls your special view (sending the version it has), your view can see “yep, new version” and return the trigger to refresh.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what my first thought was. But is this possible to do in Django view function? As I do not wish to monitor the changes of DB in javascript.

Comment: No, I'm talking about a solution where your page (i.e. javascript) polls every few seconds to check if there's a change. Django is HTTP, which is a stateless and a pull model: your view function only runs when there's an HTTP request for it. So the only way without using websockets is to have your page poll for changes every few seconds.

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? if so, how did you implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of options:

- Add a script on your page that polls (ajax) your server every few seconds for the latest data and refresh the data in place (no page refresh involved). For this you'd create a view in Django that returns the data in JSON format and your javascript would replace the data in the HTML. Pro: great user experience, page remains available. Con: Not immediate, you'd have to think of scalability as each open page will be constantly polling your server, but caching the response should be easy.
- Add a script that just polls whether the page should be refreshed. It would send some kind of version number of token identifying the current data on the page and your Django view could tell whether or not the page needs to be refreshed. Then the script would just call `location.reload()` to refresh the page. Pro: no need to fetch the data, refresh state can easily be cached, Con: still not immediate, page refresh happens when user might not be expecting it.
- Use a websocket to have an open permanent connection open to your server through which you can push the new data (or just the event: 'please refresh'). Pro: best experience, immediate update, Con: doesn't work on old browsers, complex to implement and deploy. [*django-channels*](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) would be a good starter.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking into channels.

Answer (score 0):

```
location.reload()
```

Inside the HTML inside of a Django template should suffice. Do you need this to fire on a specific event? If so, you'll want to find a way to trigger `location.reload()`, which in that case you'll need to provide a few more specifics. But essentially you'd just have some JavaScript listening for the event to reload your webpage. If you want to get advanced I'd look into [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Whenever I update the db using webapge 2. I need to trigger refresh events on all webpage 1 currently opened by clients.

Answer (score -4):

Try this in your .html code. Reloads page every minute

```
{% block content %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       location.reload(true);
       alert("The page will now refresh");
    }, 60000);  
});
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```